# Windows PDF viewer with dual page full screen mode

Tags: windows, pdf

On Mac, the built in PDF viewer has a nice feature: when I go full screen, it displays two pages of content side by side, like when one reads a book naturally. On Windows, is there a viewer that does this? With almost everybody possessing a wide screen monitor these days, having two very wide black bar on either side of the PDF is just horrible.

lang2

Answer (score 3):

Adobe acrobat reader can do it:

If you just display the right button in your toolbar, like this:
[image]

You can then click it to display your document on two pages.

If you don't like Adobe acrobat, you can try [Nuance Pdf Reader](http://www.nuance.com/products/pdf-reader/index.htm). The option is here:
[image: nuance]

Comment: would like to avoid adobe if i can ....

Comment: [Nuance PDF reader](http://www.nuance.com/products/pdf-reader/index.htm) can also do it then.

Comment: [SumatraPDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html) doesn't do it automatically for all PDFs in Full Screen view, but you can switch to "Book View" before switching to Full Screen.